# Why is webpack appending "-es5" and "es2015" to my Typescript files?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Webpack is converting my typescript files into Javascript files, but it appending `-es5` to the name. For example, I want the file to be called `background.js` but it's rendering out 4 files:

- `background-es5.js`
- `background-es5.js.map`
- `background-es2015.js`
- `background-es2015.js.map`

Here is my Webpack file `custom-webpack.config.js`:

```
const ExtensionReloader = require('webpack-extension-reloader')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "background/background":
        "src/background/background.ts",
  },
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [new ExtensionReloader({
    reloadPage: true,
    entries: {
        background: 'background/background'
    }
  })
]
};
```

Here is my **`browserlist`** file:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .browserlistrc file. If you are targeting IE11, that would explain why Angular is outputting two bundles - one for legacy browsers, and one for modern browsers.

Angular uses differential loading to load the correct bundle at runtime:

For example, using the `nomodule` attribute:

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.f790d2b83f74a52615e1.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.f790d2b83f74a52615e1.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

If this is the case, you can resolve this by commenting out the line `IE 11`

Also, check your `tsconfig.json` file. Make sure you are targeting es2017:

```
   compilerOptions: {
      target: 'es2017'
   }
```

If you targeting, es5, that may also explain it.

Comment: In tsconfig, I am targeting `es2015`. Also I don't have IE11 in browserlist